# Analyzing Entityframework performance

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

I am trying to look at a performance problem with EF core 6 and Oracle 19. EF is configured to use notracking.

I have enabled detailed logging with EF and it shows:

`Executed DbCommand (1,286ms) [Parameters=`

I am also tracking the query duration with a stopwatch:

```
    var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var data = await repo.GetData(10000) //request 10k items
    watch.Stop();
    var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    Console.WriteLine("elapsed time:" + elapsedMs + " ms");
```

This shows 3692 ms. It takes a total of almost 4 seconds before the data is received by the code. So the query takes around 1 second, what happens in the other 3 seconds? Is it possible to get a more detailed logging than what I am doing now?

Comment: Yes, the connection to the DB. The rest is the network latency. The query itself executed on the DB Server takes 1,286ms and in the code 3692 ms because of the network.

Comment: Take 1 record and measure time.